# Extract inline C# code from apsx files

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

Is there a way/tool to extract inline C# code from within an ASPX file to a code-behind file?

We want to separate the code from the HTML (lots of pages) in an application we inherited.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're doing a bit of refactoring so I'd suggest you look into [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/index.html) or [Refactor! Pro](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/). Both tools will be able to assist you.